# Extracting and Transforming Data from local MySQL to Azure Synapse Data Warehouse

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I'm trying to setup a Demo Data Warehouse in Azure Synapse. I would like to extract data from a local MySQL database, transform and aggregate some data and store it in fact-/dimension tables in Azure Synapse Analytics.

Currently I have an instance of Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Data Factory. I created a connection to my MySQL database in Data Factory and my thought was, i can use this connector as input for a new Data Flow, which transforms the dataset and stores it to my destination dataset, which is linked to my Azure Synapse Data Warehouse.

The Problem is, Data Factory just support some Azure Services like Azure Data Lake or Azure SQL Database as Source for a new Data Flow.

What would be the best practice for solving this Problem? Create an Instance of Azure SQL Database, copy the Data from the local MySQL Database to the Azure SQL Database and use it then as Source for a new Data Flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice here is to use the Copy Activity in an ADF pipeline to land the data from MySQL into Parquet in Blob or ADLS G2, then transform the data using Data Flows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would a Data Lake or Blob Storage also be the most sensible solution if i only have structured Data coming from an SQL only environment (regarding Performance)?

Comment: In most cases, direct connectors from ADF Data Flows directly in the Source transform will perform better. But there are certainly scenarios where having separate pipelines that just incrementally maintain the data from SQL in the lake can perform better. That's more of an ELT pattern with staging in the lake.